# how to pass parameter in render action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, render

```
def create
    @emppede = Emppede.new(params[:emppede])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @emppede.save
        format.html { redirect_to :action => :index, :id => @emppede.ad }
        format.json { render json: @emppede, status: :created, location: @emppede }
      else

        format.html { render action: "new", :id => @emppede.ad } *(....error)*
        format.json { render json: @emppede.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have to pass id in new method. Here if the data is save properly then it goes to index method. But if not then it should go to new but with the params id. How could i pass the params through render action? Here i want to do but param id is not passed to new method. I highlighted that part by error.
If i do

```
 format.html { redirect_to :action => :new, :id => @emppede.ad }
```

Then it do not give errors message...

I have to pass user id  to the new method so that i can pass it through the form and save.

```
<div id="employm" style="display:none">


    <%= f.text_field :ad, :value=> @id%>

            </div>
```

But when the form get error it render to new but here i have to send the
 id which is in  `@emppede.ad`. 
How can i do  this?
Since in order to enter in new method there should be id passed

```
redirect_to :action => :new, :id => @id
```

Comment: Do you really have to pass the `id` to the `new` view? You already have your `@emppede` set, use it in your view.

Comment: this is another id i have to send that is in my form . I have to send id from here since my new method is like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All instance variables you define in your controller action are present in the view.
So if you define `@id = 11` in your controller you can access it in the view using `<%= @id %>`.

If you want to do this over a redirect you can simply can access the `parameters` inside the view (or use them first in the controller and then use the instance method above.

Your posted code is a bit cryptic, but render will not enter the `new` method but only render the `new.html.erb` in the current context. So if you declared @id in your create action and render new you'll have it present.

When redirecting to :action you'll have to pass the @id as a parameter.

Comment: I have to pass user id  to the new method so that i can pass it through the form and save.                                             <div id="employm" style="display:none">
    <%= f.text_field :ad, :value=> @id%>
    </div> But when the form get error it render to new but here i have to send the id which is in  @emppede.ad. How can i do  this?

Comment: Can u edit my question so that i can get result. I am messed up.

Comment: Thanks I got it simply i have to define  @id= @emppede.ad  inside create method then it is ok ....

Answer (score 7):

Render will look for "new.html", it won't enter into the new method.